# Bizarre, registering/enqueueing / plugins_url() custom css in Admin of wp 3.3.1

Tags: wordpress, admin

I have a problem with registering and enqueueing a css file (in an admin form)
I'm trying to register and enqueue my css file in admin using admin_init, with

```
 $myStyleUrl = plugins_url('/SBaronAdmin/MyPopupStyle.css'); // Path relative to the plugins URL     
 $myStyleFile = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/SBaronAdmin/MyPopupStyle.css';but
```

If I check eg.
     echo $myStyleUrl;     //result =  http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/SBaronAdmin/MyPopupStyle.css
If I check via my browser, that url is perfectly correct.
yet,..
     if ( file_exists($myStyleUrl) )  //does not find it ??

Checking if the other exists is fine i.e.  "$myStyleFile

Anyone please?
thx

Answer (score 0):

The file_exists() function is meant to check if a local file exists, so if you pass it a URL, it will try to look up that path on the local filesystem (and fail).

When you call plugins_url(), you should pass a second argument, which is the relative path. That way if someone renames your plugin folder, it won't break.

Based on your code snippet, I assume you're referencing the sample at the following URL:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style#Examples

Notice that when they check if the file exists, they use $myStyleFile, not $myStyleUrl. That's what you want to do as well.

```
<?php
function add_my_stylesheet() {
    $myStyleUrl = plugins_url('MyPopupStyle.css', __FILE__);
    $myStyleFile = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/style.css';
    if ( file_exists($myStyleFile) ) {
        wp_register_style( 'SBaronAdminStyle', $myStyleUrl );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'SBaronAdminStyle' );
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Hook for adding SB admin menus
add_action('admin_menu', 'Add_SBMenu_Pages');
function Add_SBMenu_Pages() {
     add_menu_page('Page title', 'SandwichBaron', 'manage_options', 'my-top-level-handle', 'fn_SBMenus_page');

     //some other identical add submenu pages........

    $page = add_submenu_page( 'my-top-level-handle', 'Page title', 'Platters', 'manage_options', 'my-submenu-handle4', 
                    'fn_SB_Branches4_Menus_page');
    add_action( 'admin_print_styles-' . $page, 'my_plugin_admin_styles' );
}

function my_plugin_admin_styles() {
      /*
       * It will be called only on $Page page, enqueue our stylesheet here
       */
      wp_enqueue_style( 'myPopupStyle' );
  }
```